# Enter password for a sudo command in a chain of commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

In Linux how can I enter the password for one of the commands in a chain of commands which requires a sudo. One example which I can think of is when after running a long compile job, I want to shutdown the machine.

```
make ; sudo init 0
```

I want the shutdown command to run only after make finishes, but would like to enter the password right away, because I won't be there when the first command is done. Also, I don't want to run "make" with super user privileges. So switching to root and running the commands is also out of the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo sh -c "su -c 'make' $USER && init 0"
```

Change your uid early and often.  That's the Chicago way!

Comment: Is this what the above command does? You run a shell as super user, but within that the "su" command runs "make" as the current user, after which "init 0" is run as super user.

Comment: @Rohit: Yes, that is exactly what it does.  Note the use of double-quotes so that $USER is interpreted in the context of the outer shell before the uid has been changed.  Also, the superuser can run su without having to supply a password.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `sudo -v` to update the `sudo` timestamp - this means you won't need to enter a password for *x* minutes (default is 5).  You can change the timeout by editing the `timestamp_timeout` in the [sudoers](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/sudoers.5.php) file.

You also might want to change your command to

```
make && sudo init 0
```

which will only shut down if make completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)
to automate the password input.

Here's a simple HOW-TO for expect and passwords: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/56066

Another possibility is to edit your /etc/sudoers and set your user to be able to use sudo without password. if you check the file it will be explained in the comments there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pipe the password into `sudo`?

`make; echo 'password' | sudo -S init 0`

Comment: +1, this is what i need to do: `System.exec("make; echo 'password'  | sudo -S init 6");`

Answer (score 0):

Change the timeout for sudo to something long enough to cover your usage, then run something like `sudo echo` to authenticate, then run your other commands. As long as the password timeout hasn't been reached, it should execute without asking again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that to your sudoers file

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/init
```

where username is the username you want to allow.

Comment: Works, but has the sideeffect of the user being to execute `sudo init 0` anytime, without password (while the question did want the permission to fade afterwards)... don't leave your terminal unattended after this.

Comment: yep, an insecure solution, but most distributions allow the user to shutdown/reboot through the GUI anyway.